# DPDK l3fwd-acl application is unable to send or receive using net_tap PMD using namespaces

Tags: tap, dpdk

I compiled dpdk 19.11.11 version to test l3fwd-acl.  After starting it in a VirtualBox instance with 2 CPUs and 2 ports I have  used 2 TAP interfaces to simulate 2 network interfaces for putting traffic over one and getting that back over another.  I have used the following command (and get the following output):

```
sam@sam-VirtualBox:~/prac/dpdk-stable-19.11.11/examples/l3fwd-acl/build/app$ sudo ./l3fwd-acl -l 1 -n 1 --vdev=net_tap0 --vdev=net_tap1 -- -p 0x3 -P --config="(0,0,1),(1,0,1)" --rule_ipv4="./ipv4_rules.db" --rule_ipv6="./ipv6_rules.db"
[sudo] password for sam:
EAL: Detected 2 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: PCI device 0000:00:03.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:100e net_e1000_em
EAL: PCI device 0000:00:08.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:100f net_e1000_em
EAL: PCI device 0000:00:09.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:100f net_e1000_em
EAL: PCI device 0000:00:0a.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:100f net_e1000_em
Promiscuous mode selected
ACL option are:
rule_ipv4: ./ipv4_rules.db
rule_ipv6: ./ipv6_rules.db
scalar: 0
L3FWDACL: IPv4 Route entries 1:
        1:0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 0 : 65535 0 : 65535 0x0/0x0 0xffffffff-0x1ffffffe-0x2
L3FWDACL: IPv4 ACL entries 1:
        1:0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 0 : 65535 10101 : 10101 0x6/0xfe 0xffffffff-0x1fffffff-0xf0000000
L3FWDACL: IPv6 Route entries 1:
        1:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000/0 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000/0 0 : 65535 0 : 65535 0x0/0x0 0xffffffff-0x1fffffff-0x1
L3FWDACL: IPv6 ACL entries 0:
acl context <l3fwd-acl-ipv40>@0x1004d8040
  socket_id=0
  alg=3
  max_rules=100000
  rule_size=96
  num_rules=2
  num_categories=1
  num_tries=1
acl context <l3fwd-acl-ipv60>@0x100fb0440
  socket_id=0
  alg=3
  max_rules=100000
  rule_size=192
  num_rules=1
  num_categories=1
  num_tries=1
Initializing port 0 ... Creating queues: nb_rxq=1 nb_txq=1... Port 0 modified RSS hash function based on hardware support,requested:0x3bffc configured:0
 Address:08:00:27:E8:C1:2B, Allocated mbuf pool on socket 0
txq=1,0,0
Initializing port 1 ... Creating queues: nb_rxq=1 nb_txq=1... Port 1 modified RSS hash function based on hardware support,requested:0x3bffc configured:0
 Address:08:00:27:1D:45:A5, txq=1,0,0

Skipping disabled port 2

Skipping disabled port 3

Initializing rx queues on lcore 1 ... rxq=0,0,0 rxq=1,0,0

Checking link status..............................done
Port0 Link Up. Speed 1000 Mbps full-duplex
Port1 Link Up. Speed 1000 Mbps full-duplex
L3FWD: entering main loop on lcore 1
L3FWD:  -- lcoreid=1 portid=0 rxqueueid=0
L3FWD:  -- lcoreid=1 portid=1 rxqueueid=0
```

After that I assigned an IP address for dtap0 and dtap1 following the commands shown in the accepted solution at:[No traffic emerges in DPDK RX/TX Callbacks Sample Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277448/no-traffic-emerges-in-dpdk-rx-tx-callbacks-sample-application?rq=1)

I tried ping from one tap interface to another using the IP assigned but cannot get any response.  What could be the problem?

[EDIT 2]
Using the above steps we are able to ping from tap0 namespace to namespace tap1 but we observed packet loss during that communication.

```
The rules files are:
1) ipv4_rules.db
+++
R0.0.0.0/0  12.12.12.2/32 0 : 65535 0 : 65535 0/0xfe 1
R0.0.0.0/0  12.12.12.1/32 0 : 65535 0 : 65535 0/0xfe 0
+++
2) ipv6_rules.db
+++
R0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0/0 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0/0 0 : 65535 0 : 65535 0x00/0x00 0
 +++
Apart from ping with packet loss, not able to exchange traffic using "netcat" or "socat" though.  Commands used for netcat/socat were:
a) Listener side:
sudo ip netns exec tap1 nc -l 1567
OR
sudo ip netns exec tap1 socat TCP4-LISTEN:1567,fork EXEC:cat
b) Sender side:
sudo ip netns exec tap0 nc 12.12.12.2 1567
```

Comment: looks like you are using the right settings, can you please run tcpdump to capture the mac address from dtap0 and dtap1?

Comment: 1) The mac address for dtap1 on the namespace "ns1":
+++
$ sudo ip netns exec ns1 ip a
...
11: dtap1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 76:1b:9e:a9:0c:e7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 11.0.0.2/24 brd 11.0.0.255 scope global dtap1
+++
2) For dtap0 on the default namespace of the VirtualBox VM:
+++
10: dtap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc multiq state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 56:0c:89:f1:8c:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
 +++

Comment: The tcpdump outputs do not show the mac addresses; hence "ip a" ouputs.

Comment: `tcpdump -eni <interface name> -Q in` for ingress traffic and `tcpdump -eni <interface anme> -Q out` for egress traffic

Comment: ~$ sudo tcpdump -eni dtap0 -Q inout
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on dtap0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
19:12:28.357963 8a:c7:ef:94:f5:02 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 11.0.0.2 tell 11.0.0.1, length 28
...

~$ sudo ip netns exec ns1 tcpdump -eni dtap1 -Q inout
listening on dtap1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
...

Only dtap0 (in default namespace shows the ARP request)
dtap1 in "ns1" namespace shows nothing

Comment: Not sure if you could follow my comment above. I tried to ping from default namespace where dtap0 has IP of 11.0.0.1 to datp1 in namespace "ns1" that has IP of 11.0.0.2.  The tcpdump output for dtap0 shows ARP request:  `21:26:20.681220 8a:c7:ef:94:f5:02 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 11.0.0.2 tell 11.0.0.1, length 28`  .  and the tcpdump output dtap1 is empty.  Do I need to create an ARP entry manually so that dtap0 can talk with dtap1 in another namespace "ns1"?

Comment: lets have a live debug, as I recollect 'if dtap0 and dtap1 has the right ip address, pign wholuld work'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L3fwd-acl works with IP packets only, for all non IP packets it drops. Hence with TAP PMD I had to follow the changes as

1. Disable any NIC PCIe device using `--no-pci`
2. Use new commands as `sudo ./build/l3fwd-acl --file-prefix=mytest -l 2-4 --vdev=net_tap0 --vdev=net_tap1 --no-pci  -- -P -p 3 --config="(0,0,4),(1,0,3)"  --rule_ipv4=ipv4-sample.db  --rule-ipv6=ipv6-sample.db --eth-dest=0,<mac address of DPDK TAP0>  --eth-dest=1,<mac address of DPDK TAP1>`
3. edit ip-sample.db file with the entries to be assigned for `dtap0 and dtap1`.
4. refer section [24.1.3](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/l3_forward_access_ctrl.html) to identify the format and for default drop [rule](http://mails.dpdk.org/archives/dev/2015-April/016483.html)
5. start the application and use the following netns commands.

```
sudo ip netns add tap0
sudo ip netns add tap1
ip netns
ip netns exec tap0 ifconfig -a
ip netns exec tap1 ifconfig -a
sudo ip link set dtap0 netns tap0
sudo ip link set dtap1 netns tap1
ip netns exec tap0 ifconfig -a
ip netns exec tap1 ifconfig -a
sudo ip netns exec tap0 ifconfig dtap0 12.12.12.1 up
sudo ip netns exec tap1 ifconfig dtap1 12.12.12.2 up
```

If we perform `sudo ip netns exec tap0 ping 12.12.12.2` the ARP packets will be dropped since it is not IP packet. To prevent this from happening, add static ARP entries for dtap0 and dtap1 within namespace `tap0 and tap1`. This will make the kernel to sent out ICMP packets will be then routed by L3FWD ACL program.

Note: one can test the same using DPDK L2FWD with `--file-prefix=test --no-pci --vdev=net_tap0 --vdev=net_tap1  -l 12-13 -- -p 3 -T 1 --no-mac-updating`

[EDIT-1] **Question:** how to assign static MAC for TAP PMD?
***Answer***: please refer the [TAP PMD link](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/tap.html) for using option `mac='desired mac address'` to achieve the same.

[EDIT-2] with new linux kernel multiple rx-tx queues are created for TAP PMD> With DPDK example l3fwd-acl based on total lcores RX-TX are created. hence if we do not read from all queues packets are missed.

To work around this problem only use 1 lcore.

CMD: `sudo ./build/l3fwd-acl --file-prefix=mytest -l 2 --no-pci  --vdev=net_tap0,mac=10:20:30:40:50:66 --vdev=net_tap1,mac=10:20:30:40:50:60 -- -P -p 3 --config="(0,0,2),(1,0,2)"  --rule_ipv4=ipv4-sample.db  --rule_ipv6=ipv6-sample.db --eth-dest=0,10:20:30:40:50:66  --eth-dest=1,10:20:30:40:50:60`

Proc-info: `sudo ./dpdk-proc-info --no-pci --file-prefix=mytest   -- -p 3 --stats | grep -v ": 0"`

[image]

Comment: sudo ip netns exec tap0 tcpdump -eni dtap0 -Q inout  ; listening on dtap0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
12:40:52.951174 82:2d:20:f0:9c:3b > 2a:3e:72:9a:8b:dd, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 12.12.12.2 > 12.12.12.1: ICMP echo request, id 24564, seq 302, length 64
//
sudo ip netns exec tap1 tcpdump -eni dtap1 -Q inout;  listening on dtap1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
12:41:03.193128 82:2d:20:f0:9c:3b > 2a:3e:72:9a:8b:dd, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 12.12.12.2 > 12.12.12.1: ICMP echo request, id 24564, seq 312, length 64

Comment: ping is still not successful. The relevant outputs: +++ `sudo ip netns exec tap0 ip a link/ether 2a:3e:72:9a:8b:dd // sudo ip netns exec tap1 ip a link/ether 82:2d:20:f0:9c:3b // sudo ip netns exec tap0 arp -a ? (12.12.12.2) at 82:2d:20:f0:9c:3b // sudo ip netns exec tap1 arp -a ? (12.12.12.1) at 2a:3e:72:9a:8b:dd // sudo ip netns exec tap1 ping 12.12.12.1 5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4099ms +++

Comment: @sam ping is successful for 1 RX and multi RX queue as per the live debug. Please accept and upvote to close the current question to help others